# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' Beautifulsoup wrong class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a house's price of this link : https://www.bienici.com/recherche/achat/france?page=2

And I need to know what's wrong with my program ?

My program :

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import csv

 with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow("Prix") 

     for i in range(1, 20):
         url = "https://www.bienici.com/recherche/achat/france?page=%s" % i
         soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
         data = soup.find(class_="resultsListContainer")

         for data in data.find_all(class_="sideListItemContainerInTableForListInResult"):
             prix = data.find("span", {"class": "thePrice"})
             prix = prix.text if prix else ""

             writer.writerow(prix)
```

I get this error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "1.py", line 16, in <module>
        for data in data.find_all(class_="sideListItemContainerInTableForListInResult"):
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I think my error is in the class_="sideListItemContainerInTableForListInResult" , but when I inspect the html code I think it's the right one !!

Comment: the page is likely dynamic if you're seeing it in the html, but it's not there when you pull it with `requests`. You'll need to either a) use Selenium, or b) see if there's an endpoint API, or c) it could be within the `script` tags in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can access the data through the json response. You'll have to play around with the paramters and dig through the json structure to pull out what you want need, but look like quite a bit of data you are able to grab:

```
import requests

payload = {'filters': '{"size":24,"from":0,"filterType":"buy","propertyType":["house","flat"],"newProperty":false,"page":2,"resultsPerPage":24,"maxAuthorizedResults":2400,"sortBy":"relevance","sortOrder":"desc","onTheMarket":[true],"limit":"ih{eIzjhZ?q}qrAzaf}AlrD?rvfrA","showAllModels":false,"blurInfoType":["disk","exact"]}'}


url = 'https://www.bienici.com/realEstateAds.json'  
response = requests.get(url, params = payload).json()

for prop in response['realEstateAds']:
    title = prop['title']
    city = prop['city']
    desc = prop['description']
    price = prop['price']

    print ('%s - %s\n%s\n%s' %(price, title, city, desc))
```

**Output:**

```
print ('%s - %s\n%s\n%s' %(price, title, city, desc))
1190000 - BALMA - Bien d'exception 12 pièces 400 m2
Pin-Balma
- EXCLUSIVITÉ - Bien d'exception à BALMA (31130) . - 400 m2 - 12 pièces - 7 chambres - Sur 3000 m2 de terrain. . Luxe, calme et volupté dans cette magnifique et très rare maison divisée en deux lots d'habitation communicants (qui peuvent aussi être indépendants). L'un de 260 m2 et l'autre de 140 m2. Chacun avec son entrée, son séjour, sa cuisine, ses salles de bains et pièces d'eau, ses chambres, ses terrasses et ses équipements de qualité. Et ce, ouvrant le champ des possibles quant aux projets potentiels !. . Cette bâtisse de prestige du milieu du XVIIIème siècle a vu ses rénovations et prestations inhérentes réalisées avec des matériaux et des façons d'excellence.. . Sur les 3000 m2 de terrain, un jardin paysager orne les abords de la maison et de la piscine. Puis, vous trouverez un pré et un bois privé qui réveilleront vos aspirations bucoliques. Vous pourrez ainsi vous blottir dans un écrin précieux niché à proximité de TOULOUSE.. . Vos hôtes et vous serez à proximité des commodités, des transports (dont le métro), des cliniques, des établissements scolaires et des hypermarchés ; et tout aussi proches d'Airbus (BLAGNAC et Défense), du CEAT, des SSII, de Orange Business Services, etc.. . Recevez notre invitation au voyage, là où tout n'est qu'ordre et beauté, Luxe, calme et volupté.. . Visite virtuelle disponible en agence ou en LiveRoom avec un de nos conseillers.
```

To get to a csv, you'll need to convert to a dataframe. Now the json structure is nested, so there are some columns that won't be entirelly flattened out. There are ways to handle that, but to get a basic dataframe:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(response['realEstateAds'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
   accountType  adCreatedByPro adType adTypeFR  addressKnown  agencyFeePercentage                                       agencyFeeUrl  annualCondominiumFees             availableDate  balconyQuantity  balconySurfaceArea  bathroomsQuantity  bedroomsQuantity                                      blurInfo.bbox  blurInfo.centroid.lat  blurInfo.centroid.lon blurInfo.origin  blurInfo.position.lat  blurInfo.position.lon  blurInfo.radius blurInfo.type                 city  condominiumPartsQuantity                                        description  descriptionTextLength district.code_insee district.cp  district.id  district.id_polygone  district.id_type district.insee_code                                   district.libelle                                      district.name district.postal_code  district.type_id  enclosedParkingQuantity  endOfPromotedAsExclusive energyClassification  energyValue      exposition feesChargedTo  floor  floorQuantity greenhouseGazClassification  greenhouseGazValue hasAirConditioning hasAlarm hasBalcony hasCaretaker hasCellar hasDoorCode hasElevator hasFirePlace hasGarden hasIntercom hasPool hasSeparateToilet hasTerrace                    heating  highlightMailContact                              id isCalm isCondominiumInProcedure isDisabledPeopleFriendly isExclusiveSaleMandate isInCondominium isRefurbished isStudio  landSurfaceArea          modificationDate needHomeStaging newOrOld  newProperty  nothingBehindForm  parkingPlacesQuantity                                             photos postalCode    price  priceHasDecreased  pricePerSquareMeter  priceWithoutFees propertyType           publicationDate          reference  roomsQuantity  showerRoomsQuantity  status.autoImported  status.closedByUser  status.highlighted  status.is3dHighlighted  status.isLeading  status.onTheMarket  surfaceArea  terracesQuantity             thresholdDate                                              title  toiletQuantity transactionType      userRelativeData.accountIds  userRelativeData.canChangeOnTheMarket  userRelativeData.canModifyAd  userRelativeData.canModifyAdBlur  userRelativeData.canSeeAddress  userRelativeData.canSeeContacts  userRelativeData.canSeeExactPosition  userRelativeData.canSeePublicationCertificateHtml  userRelativeData.canSeePublicationCertificatePdf  userRelativeData.canSeeRealDates  userRelativeData.canSeeStats userRelativeData.importAccountId  userRelativeData.isAdModifier  userRelativeData.isAdmin  userRelativeData.isFavorite  userRelativeData.isNetwork  userRelativeData.isOwner                  userRelativeData.searchAccountIds                                       virtualTours  with360  with3dModel workToDo  yearOfConstruction
0       agency            True    buy    vente          True                  NaN  https://www.immoceros.fr/mentions-legales-hono...                 2517.0                       NaN              NaN                 NaN                1.0                 3             [2.27006, 48.92827, 2.27006, 48.92827]              48.928270               2.270060          manual              48.928270               2.270060              NaN         exact             Colombes                      47.0  COLOMBES | Agent-Sarre - Champarons |\r\nSitué...                   1149               92025       92700       100331                100331                 1               92025                                Fossés Jean Bouvier                     Colombes - Fossés Jean Bouvier                92700                 1                      NaN                         0                    D       197.00             NaN        seller    5.0            6.0                           B                9.00                NaN      NaN      False          NaN     False         NaN        True          NaN     False         NaN     NaN               NaN       True     électricité individuel                 False              ag922079-195213238    NaN                      NaN                      NaN                   True            True           NaN      NaN              NaN  2019-05-11T08:53:15.943Z             NaN   ancien        False               True                    2.0  [{'url_photo': 'http://photos.ubiflow.net/9220...      92700   469000              False          5097.826087          469000.0         flat  2019-04-23T18:42:59.742Z  VA1952-IMMOCEROS2              4                  1.0                 True                False               False                   False              True                True        92.00               NaN                       NaN  COLOMBES  | APPARTEMENT A VENDRE | 4 PIECES - ...             1.0             buy  [ubiflow-easybusiness-ag922079]                                  False                         False                             False                           False                            False                                 False                                              False                                             False                             False                         False         558bbfd06fbf04e50075bbce                          False                     False                        False                       False                     False  [ubiflow-easybusiness-ag922079, contract-type-...  [{'originalUrl': 'https://www.nodalview.com/bK...     True        False      NaN                 NaN
1       agency            True    buy    vente          True                  NaN                                                NaN                    NaN                       NaN              NaN                 NaN                NaN                 1  [7.251231, 43.700846999999996, 7.251231, 43.70...              43.700847               7.251231          custom              43.700847               7.251231              NaN         exact                 Nice                       NaN  A vendre à Nice dans le quartier Grosso / Tzar...                   1542               06088       06000       300102                300102                 1               06088                            Parc Impérial - Le Piol                     Nice - Parc Impérial - Le Piol                06000                 1                      NaN                         0                    E       270.00           Ouest           NaN    NaN            7.0                           C               14.00                NaN      NaN        NaN          NaN       NaN         NaN        True          NaN       NaN        True     NaN               NaN        NaN                Individuel                  False                   apimo-2871096    NaN                      NaN                      NaN                   True             NaN           NaN      NaN              NaN  2019-04-25T17:04:27.723Z             NaN      NaN        False               True                    NaN  [{'url_photo': 'https://d1qfj231ug7wdu.cloudfr...      06000   215000              False          4383.282365               NaN         flat  2019-04-04T18:04:38.323Z               1508              2                  NaN                 True                False               False                   False             False                True        49.05               NaN                       NaN  Nice François Grosso : F2 dernier étage, terra...             NaN             buy                     [apimo-3120]                                  False                         False                             False                           False                            False                                 False                                              False                                             False                             False                         False         5913331e150de0009ce38406                          False                     False                        False                       False                     False  [apimo-3120, contract-type-basic, 5913331e150d...  [{'originalUrl': 'https://www.nodalview.com/PX...     True        False    False                 NaN
2       agency            True    buy    vente          True                  NaN                                                NaN                    NaN                       NaN              NaN                 NaN                NaN                 0  [7.2526839999999995, 43.69589099999998, 7.2526...              43.695891               7.252684          custom              43.695891               7.252684              NaN         exact                 Nice                       NaN  Joli studio entièrement meublé et équipé à ven...                   1205               06088       06000       300070                300070                 1               06088                                           Gambetta                                    Nice - Gambetta                06000                 1                      NaN                         0                    D       224.47             Est           NaN    2.0            6.0                           B                8.49               True      NaN        NaN          NaN       NaN         NaN        True          NaN       NaN        True     NaN               NaN        NaN                Individuel                  False                   apimo-1008273    NaN                      NaN                      NaN                   True             NaN           NaN     True              NaN  2019-04-24T17:02:19.834Z             NaN      NaN        False               True                    NaN  [{'url_photo': 'https://d1qfj231ug7wdu.cloudfr...      06000   145000              False          6722.299490               NaN         flat  1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z               1496              1                  NaN                 True                False               False                   False             False                True        21.57               NaN  2019-03-29T09:52:38.387Z        Nice proche mer : studio meublé avec balcon             NaN             buy                     [apimo-3120]                                  False                         False                             False                           False                            False                                 False                                              False                                             False                             False                         False         5913331e150de0009ce38406                          False                     False                        False                       False                     False  [apimo-3120, contract-type-basic, 5913331e150d...  [{'originalUrl': 'https://www.nodalview.com/xV...     True        False    False                 NaN
3       agency            True    buy    vente          True                  NaN  http://www.willman.fr/i/redac/honoraires?honof...                    NaN  2017-12-27T00:00:00.000Z              NaN                 NaN                3.0                 3  [7.165397, 43.666337999999996, 7.165397, 43.66...              43.666338               7.165397        accounts              43.666338               7.165397              NaN         exact       Cagnes-sur-Mer                       NaN  Située dans le quartier recherché des Bréguièr...                   1229               0
```

Then to save it:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `data` is `NoneType`, i.e. `data = soup.find(class_="resultsListContainer")` is returning `None`, which means the for loop will fail.

I don't know enough about the exact problem you're trying to solve to know if this is a problem with your code or if the website sometimes doesn't have anything in the "resultListContainer" class. If it is the case that sometime this is missing, you can do a check before reaching the for loop to make sure the `data` variable is not `None`.